# I want to fetch second children data with query or query criteria

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to fetch the children items fields

It is a nested document something like this

```json
{
   "title": "home", 
   "active": false,
   "level": "1",
   "children": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "clothing",
            "type": "sub",
            "active": false,
            "level": "2",
            "children": [
             { 
                 "id":1,
                "title": "New",
                "type": "sup",
                "active": false,
                "level": "3",
                 }
             ]
        }
   ]
}
```

This is my controller get Mapping for fetch submenu items fields

I am trying to fetch this with `Query (Criteria)` but it is not working

```java
    @GetMapping("/menus/{id}/submenu/{Id}/children/{childId}")
    public Children findChildrenById(SubMenu subMenu, @PathVariable("id") long id,
            @PathVariable("Id") long submenuId, @PathVariable("childId") long childId) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(
                Criteria.where("id").is(id).and("children.id").is(submenuId).and("children.children.$[].id").is(childId));
        if (subMenu.getChildren() != null) {
            for (Children child : subMenu
                    .getChildren()) {
                return template.findOne(query, child.getClass());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I Want to fetch the nested document

Comment: It seems that you do not have `id` field in your nested document. And you are filtering on it with elemMatch. I suggest you to read this doc: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this (and read comments in code for infos):

```
@PatchMapping("/menus-items-childrens/{id}")
public MenuItems updateSubMenuItems(@RequestBody MenuItems menuItems, @PathVariable("id") long id) {
        
    Query query = new Query();

    // assuming you want to update all the nested documents given the id of the main document
    // you only need to filter on the id field
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(id));

    // '$[]' is required to update all nested documents
    Update update = new Update().set("children.$[].active", true);
    
    return MongoOperations.findAndModify(query, update, MenuItems.class);

}
```

See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/write-operations/embedded-arrays/#matching-all-array-elements for more info

Comment: Hey I try this way also . it ok . but the other fields are getting null. and it is not updating submenu . this query updating directly menu items .....   See this

Comment: yes i was wrong, see my edited post

Comment: Please let me know if it works and please accept my answer if it does

Comment: ofter this exception this  exception is coming: Failed to instantiate java.util.Set using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments \r\n\tat org.springframework.data.mapping.model

Comment: it works here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/lDQDjPBjB8L
Maybe you left some bad data in your collection

Comment: see I m using spring boot and . I know its working but the other fields are getting null .        I don't know it my first time with mongodb.

Comment: please show us all the documents in your collection so that we can help you

Comment: It working now . I was passing manuitems id . not submenu id that's why its not working . now its fine

Comment: Can you please tell me . how can I update children without  Id

Comment: Please edit your question with more details. If you want to update all children of all menuitems, remove the `query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(id));` line.

Comment: okay  . I have one more children under children and I want to update this children . but the children don't have an Id . and the code is exact sample that I post here

Comment: I edit my question  Json code .  I have one more children and I want to update this also . But whiteout Id.